# Acceder a Base de datos C#

Tags: c#

¡Buenas tardes!

Al intentar acceder a una base de datos con C# me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: ERROR EN CMD]

El código en primer lugar elimina todos los datos de la tabla "usuarios" de la base de datos, seguidamente realiza una consulta a un servidor Active Directory, recoge los datos de todos los usuarios de éste y finalmente realiza un "INSERT" con todos los datos de los usuarios, para así tener la base de datos siempre sincronizada con el servidor Active Directory.

Por algún motivo que no alcanzo a entender (dado a mi escasa experiencia con C#) la conexión a la base de datos no se hace correctamente, deduzco que debe debido al orden a la hora de abrir la conexión a ésta o alguna tontería similar, pero no alcanzo a encontrar el error.

Código:

```
        static public DirectoryEntry AbrirConexionAD()
    {
        DirectoryEntry oDE;
        oDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.1.130", "Administrador", "1234Alumne", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        return oDE;
    }
    static SearchResultCollection ObtenerUsuariosAD()
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = AbrirConexionAD();
        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
        deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
        deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
        return results;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SearchResultCollection MyUsers = ObtenerUsuariosAD();
        if (MyUsers != null && MyUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = WIN-JF6G8TV8T77\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = ADUsers; Integrated Security = True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand orden = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    orden.Connection = connection;
                    orden.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    orden.CommandText = "DELETE FROM usuarios;";
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        orden.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("error1");
                        Console.WriteLine(e1);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (SearchResult m_User in MyUsers)
            {
                DirectoryEntry resultado = m_User.GetDirectoryEntry();
                SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIN-JF6G8TV8T77\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ADUsers; Integrated Security=true;");
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = WIN-JF6G8TV8T77\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = ADUsers; Integrated Security = True"))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand orden = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            orden.Connection = connection;
                            orden.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            orden.CommandText = "INSERT into usuarios (givenName, sn, samAccountName, userPrincipalName) VALUES (@v1, @v2, @v3, @v4)";
                            orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", resultado.Properties["givenName"].Value);
                            orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v2", resultado.Properties["sn"].Value);
                            orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v3", resultado.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
                            orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v4", resultado.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
                            try
                            {
                                connection.Open();
                                Console.WriteLine("valido");
                                orden.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Console.WriteLine("execute");
                            }
                            catch (SqlException e2)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("error2");
                                Console.WriteLine(e2);
                                string key = Console.ReadKey().ToString();  //Read what is being pressed
                                if (key == "")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("User pressed enter!");
                                    return; //stop further execution
                                }

                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("finaly");
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception fallo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No han habido resultados, error.");
                    Console.WriteLine(fallo);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La conexión con el servidor ActiveDirectory ha fallado.");
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: la imagen que pones como error no aporta el mensaje, deberias usar Console.WriteLine(fallo.Message); para obtener el mensaje del exception

Comment: dentro del foreach tienes dos conexiones a la base de datatos y solo cierras una, la otra nunca la cierras.

Comment: como te mencionaron, lo que pones sobre el error es el donde ocurrió pero no el qué ocurrió, sin ese mensaje estaríamos adivinando

Answer (score 0):

Si es un problema en la conexion seguro se deba a que `Sql Express` por defecto no permite conexiones remotas, debes habilitarlo

[Cómo conectarse a un SQL Server remoto](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-conectarse-a-un-sql-server-remoto/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes que validar que el servicio se expone para conexiones remotas y que el firewall tambien habilita el puerto

Si el servicio esta local entonces en el `connection string` usa `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Tambien deberias validar que ambas PCs estan dentro del mismo dominio y el usuario con el cual te autenticas tiene permisos de acceso al servicio de sql server.